# CSS Background-color overlapses with border on table cell in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, html-table, border, background-color

I have a table with two simple table cells:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Test1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Test2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

And I add the following CSS to the table cells:

```
td {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  background-color: #CCC;
}
```

For some reason when I view this in IE it shows the background on TOP of the border, if I uncheck the background in DOM explorer I can see the border is there.

I guess this has something to do with a parent element, but there are soooo many parent elements I can't paste all that code here.

Anyone has an idea what this might be?

Comment: Unfortunately we can't reproduce this unless you give us more code. "Why isn't my code working" questions require *at least* enough code to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Without code its a bit hard to help, what happens when you add border-style: inset; to your table css?

Answer (score 16):

if you do not want to change the positioning, try

```
background-clip: padding-box;
```

Answer (score 8):

As I expected, it was due to a position rule in CSS:

```
td {
    position: relative
}
```

No idea why this is, but removing that solved it.

Took me forever to narrow down tho, which is why i started this post in the first place, to save me time. but alright fixed now :)

Comment: Excellent. solved my issue